# Slow first page load when porting asp.net core from .net 5 to .net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have ported my application from asp.net core 5.0 to asp.net core 6.0 (following the [recommended steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) but keeping the .net core 5 hosting model) and I'm having a problem in dev: the initial load time of pages in the new version is very slow.

I have more or less pitpointed the issue to the use of Razor Runtime compilation:

```
        IMvcBuilder mvcBuilder = services
            .AddControllersWithViews(
                configure =>
                {
                    configure.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new RawJsonBodyInputFormatter()); // this allow receiving a JSON object as a string
                    configure.Filters.Add<PeppermintExceptionsFilter>();    //new UnauthorizedExceptionFilter());
                })
            .AddViewLocalization(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(option =>
            {
                option.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) => factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
            })
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            })
            .AddFluentValidation();

        if (environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            mvcBuilder.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(); // commenting out this line resolves the issue
        }
```

When the line is present, initial load for all pages takes up to 30 seconds (typically, the first page takes 30 seconds and other pages are often quicker).

If I comment out the option, then everything works fine again. This is clearly not a problem in production but it's really problematic (and frustrating) for developpement.

The problem is not present in asp.net core 5.0

Adding the `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation` option to a new .net 6.0 using the new hosting model) application *seems* to induce the same issue but I'm not sure because the compilation of pages in a nearly empty application is very quick.

Comment: IMHO - that question would fit better here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore

Answer (score 2):

(Sorry, I should have answered that long ago)

The cause of my problem is a [bug in asp.net core SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37359) that won't be fixed until "later": the runtime and compiler uses, by default, different hash algorythm to figure out if a page has changed or not.

This causes all pages to be recompolied the first time they are accessed in debug mode when `AddRuntimeCompilation` is added.

The fix is to explicitely add this option to the project's file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ChecksumAlgorithm>SHA1</ChecksumAlgorithm>
  ...
```

This fixes the issue.

Comment: Oh. My. God. THANK YOU! I've been waiting for MINUTES every time I have to restart my application. Now it starts in seconds!